# Django-Haystack no content in search index

Tags: django-haystack

Just recently I ran 'python manage.py rebuild_index -v2' to build a searchable index for Haystack-Elastisearch project. The results to the rebuild index command were:

```
Indexing 452 quorum_ sensings
  indexed 1 - 452 of 452 (by 8436).
```

When I check the index there is no data in the index.

What would cause this?

I'm using Django 1.6, Haystack 2.1, and Python 3.3.3

Here is some of my code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Quorum_Sensing(models.Model):
    IUAPAC_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    Inducer_Molecule = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Category_Inducer_Molecule = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Inducer_Name_Synonym_Abbreviation = models.TextField()
    Chemical_Nature_Inducer_Molecule = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    Natural_Synthetic = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Pubchem_Link_Inducer_Molecules = models.URLField()
    Mass_Inducer_Molecule = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Number_Amino_Acids_In_Inducer_Molecule = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    IUPAC_Chemical_ID = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    QuorumPep_Link = models.URLField()
    Amino_Acid_Sequence_Inducer = models.CharField (max_length=300)
    SMILES = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Organism_Involved = models.CharField (max_length=200)
    Strain1 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Strain2 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Strain3 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Strain4 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Strain5 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Taxonomy_Link = models.URLField()
    Pathogenic_Or_Not = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Host = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Target_Protein = models.CharField (max_length=160)
    Target_Protein_Length = models.CharField (max_length=40)
    Gene_Name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    Broad_Functional_Category_Target_Molecule = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    GI = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    NCBI_Link_Target_Molecule = models.URLField(max_length=400)
    Mode_Of_Action = models.TextField()
    UNIPROT_Link_Target_Molecule = models.URLField()
    EMBL_Link_Target_Molecule = models.URLField()
    Related_Citations = models.URLField(max_length=400)
    Annotator = models.EmailField()
```

quorum_sensing_text.txt

```
{{ object.text }}
{{ object.Category_Inducer_Molecule }}
{{ object.Amino_Acid_Sequence_Inducer }}
{{ object.Organism_Involved }}
{{ object.Target_Protein }}
{{ object.Broad_Functional_Category_Target_Molecule }}
```

search_indexes.py

```
from bacterial.models import Quorum_Sensing
from haystack import indexes


class Quorum_SensingIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True,  template_name='quorum_sensing_text.txt')
    Category_Inducer_Molecule = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Category_Inducer_Molecule', faceted=True)
    Amino_Acid_Sequence_Inducer = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Amino_Acid_Sequence_Inducer', faceted=True)
    Organism_Involved = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Organism_Involved', faceted=True)
    Target_Protein = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Target_Protein', faceted=True)
    Broad_Functional_Category_Target_Molecule = indexes.CharField(model_attr='Broad_Functional_Category_Target_Molecule',faceted=True)


    def get_model(self):
        return Quorum_Sensing

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the issue to this problem. It was a corrupted Haystack fields.py file. Fixed the file and now the "text" field is being populated